# Self compiled Clang crashed with ThreadSafeRefCountedBase when using a clang plugin with ast matcher

Tags: clang, llvm

For the same LLVM commit(`ea12216fad6e34c4638fcac8a9202c2eada0f95a`), the snapshot version of clang (from https://apt.llvm.org) didn't crash while the one compiled by myself crashed with error:

```
clang-11: /tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/include/llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h:98: void llvm::ThreadSafeRefCountedBase<clang::ast_matchers::internal::DynMatcherInterface>::Release() const [Derived = clang::ast_matchers::internal::DynMatcherInterface]: Assertion `NewRefCount >= 0 && "Reference count was already zero."' failed.
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
corrupted double-linked list
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. My build steps are straightforward:

```
cd /tmp
export CC='gcc-10 -w -static-libgcc'
export CXX='g++-10 -w -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
export TARGET_SHA=ea12216fad6e34c4638fcac8a9202c2eada0f95a
echo $TARGET_SHA
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
git checkout $TARGET_SHA
mkdir build&&cd build
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;compiler-rt" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
make

cd /tmp/llvm-project
mkdir virtualroot
pushd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/ -P cmake_install.cmake
```

After that, set environment variables with:

```
export LLVM_VIRT=/tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot
export PATH=$LLVM_VIRT/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LLVM_VIRT/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

My clang frontend plugin made use of StatementMatcher, sorry I didn't come up a way to strip it from the existing project easily. When compiled it with `-v`, the output is:

```
clang-11 -v -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -w -O2 -std=c++20 -g -fPIC -isystem../include -isystem/tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/include -shared my-plugin.cpp -o my-plugin.so -L/tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/lib -lclangToolingCore -lclangTooling -lclangFrontendTool -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangSerialization -lclangCodeGen -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangAnalysis -lclangARCMigrate -lclangRewrite -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic -lclangASTMatchers -fno-rtti  -lstdc++ -lm
clang version 11.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git ea12216fad6e34c4638fcac8a9202c2eada0f95a)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/llvm-project/virtualroot/bin/clang-11" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name my-plugin.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -fno-split-dwarf-inlining -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /home/ubuntu/Desktop/llvm-project/virtualroot/lib/clang/11.0.0 -isystem ../include -isystem /tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/ubuntu/Desktop/llvm-project/virtualroot/lib/clang/11.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -O2 -w -std=c++20 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/ubuntu/plwork/PL-working/my-plugin -ferror-limit 19 -fno-rtti -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -faddrsig -o /tmp/my-plugin-e3f54f.o -x c++ my-plugin.cpp
clang -cc1 version 11.0.0 based upon LLVM 11.0.0git default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ../include
 /tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /home/ubuntu/Desktop/llvm-project/virtualroot/lib/clang/11.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -shared -o my-plugin.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/crtbeginS.o -L/tmp/llvm-project/virtualroot/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../.. -L/home/ubuntu/Desktop/llvm-project/virtualroot/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/my-plugin-e3f54f.o -lclangToolingCore -lclangTooling -lclangFrontendTool -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangSerialization -lclangCodeGen -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangAnalysis -lclangARCMigrate -lclangRewrite -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic -lclangASTMatchers -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

I guess the problem is likely to be some discrepancy due to improper system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after compiling clang with clang-11. It seems clang and the clang plugin need to be compiled with the same compiler. (At least major version, in my case, snapshot clang compiled git clang, git clang compiled my plugin)